# Gradle Build Configuration help - Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, build.gradle, buildship

I'm using eclipse oxygen and i was trying to run Gradle Buid on build.gradle file. I have installed Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0 and also configured the dependencies. The issue is when i right click on build.gradle and try to run as, i don't have the option Grade Build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of right-clicking the `build.gradle` file **use the *Gradle Tasks* view** to execute a Gradle task:

1. ***Window > Show View > Others...: Gradle > Gradle Tasks***
2. **Double-click** a task

See also [my short video on how to execute a Gradle task](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJNzMGrbXbI&t=128s).